# How do I highlight duplicate cells across 3 columns for multiple rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a score sheet that is used to track points for trivia games. Each round has different point values that can be wagered, but you can only use each point value once per round. I would like to highlight duplicate values for each round per team across the sheet. Attached is how I would like the sheet to look after the conditional formatting. I know I can achieve this using the duplicate conditional formatting, but for 25 teams over 6 rounds, that would be 150 conditional formatting rules. I'm not looking for a single formula to solve this, just something more efficient that creating 150 rules. For the attached sheet, there is a subtotal after each round to help break up the rounds and so that I can update the teams after each round.

This is how I would like it to look with conditional formatting

[image: 1]

Comment: Just build one conditional format in cells B2:D2, then copy and paste that. If you expand your copy selection every iteration, you just need about 8 copy paste to get your 150 groups covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for one condition per team.

Apply the following condition to `B2:D5`:

```
=COUNTIF($B2:$D2,B2)>1
```

And the following condition to `F2:H5`:

```
=COUNTIF($F2:$H2,F2)>1
```

Sample:

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick. I was way overthinking it. Thank you so much!